# Remove list UICollectionView cell separators

Tags: ios, swift, list, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to build a list similiar to WhatsNewKit([WhatsNewKit](https://github.com/SvenTiigi/WhatsNewKit)) using the new CollectionView API.

My problem is that I can't seem to remove the cell separators.
I am using as a cell the UICollectionViewListCell and so far I tried to change the cell separatorLayoutGuide like this `cell.separatorLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true`
but it just tells me that it breaks the CollectionView constraints.

(  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002364b90 UILayoutGuide:0x60000390a060'UICollectionViewListCellSeparatorLayoutGuide'.height == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002364730 'UICollectionViewListCell-height-separatorLayoutGuide-constraint' UILayoutGuide:0x60000390a060'UICollectionViewListCellSeparatorLayoutGuide'.height == 0.333333   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002364730 'UICollectionViewListCell-height-separatorLayoutGuide-constraint' UILayoutGuide:0x60000390a060'UICollectionViewListCellSeparatorLayoutGuide'.height == 0.333333   (active)>)

So is there a way to remove those separators?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide the separator by changing property `showsSeparators` of `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` (you probably pass `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` to your `collectionView.collectionViewLayout` when configuring your collection view layout).

Example usage:

```
let provider = {(_: Int, layoutEnv: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
  var configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .grouped)
  configuration.showsSeparators = false // <----- hide separators
  return .list(using: configuration, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnv)
}
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: provider)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a List CollectionView not a TableView hence I don't have the separatorStyle property here.

Comment: sorry for that, I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Same as accepted answer, just with plain layout:

```
var config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
config.showsSeparators = false
        
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
        
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```